# Error : fluid responsive ads must be at least 250px wide availablewidth=0

Tags: javascript, jquery, adsense

I use JavaScript to add an Adsens ad to a specific position on the site, using the following code:

```
$AdCode1 = $("#Adscode").html();
$("#adstarget").html($AdCode1);
```

But the ads do not appear, and when I check the console, I find the following message[image]

Is there a way to transfer a responsive ad from div to another dev?

Answer (score 3):

Set min width or width="100%" to div **Adscode**

```
<div id="Adscode" style="width:100%"></div>
```

Comment: problem has been resolved. thank